# how to extract and process a parameter in the URL in the path of a Route before calling child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
        <Route path="/profile/:username">
          {!user ? 
          <Redirect to="/" /> : 
          <Profile _user={/* do something with :username before passing it in here */ } />}
        </Route>
```

This is one of the paths in my path. I need to be able to extract `:username` and do something with it before calling the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a callback to the `Route` `render` props, then u can access to the username from it's first paramter in the callback, e.g:

```
function Profile({ _user }) {
  return <h1>{_user}</h1>;
}

function Test() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          HomePage
        </Route>
        <Route
          path='/profile/:username'
          render={(props) => {
            const usernameWithAt = '@' + props.match.params.username;
            console.log(usernameWithAt);

            return false ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Profile _user={usernameWithAt} />;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```